# How to overlay float alert box on responsive website for every window resolution?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

(Please see image below for illustration)

I build my responsive website using Bootstrap 4. I want to make an alert box displaying at bottom of page and overlaying above every elements on every size of webpage.

This alert box is displayed when click on each box (In picture: Gray areas containing "Some text") and fade out after 2 seconds.

I need help about how to overlay alert box even if the size of window it is.

I also attach some code of information.

Thanks in advance.

**Picture**
[image: Picture of topic]

**HTML**

```html
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card-group">

               <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5>.....Some Text.....</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5>.....Some Text.....</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                (More div blocks here)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
 

    .card{
    width: 14rem; 
    height: 8rem; 
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    transition: 0.3s;
    color: #333333;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.card:hover{ 
    background-color: rgba(71, 172, 255,1);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.card-body{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center
}
```

Comment: Suggest you research "Fixed positioning"

Comment: "Fixed positioning" is what I need, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code snippet,

If you wanted to create your own alert design you could also do this in a similar way.

If you need the alert box in the same place every time have a look at the css for .alert-fixed replace *alert alert-primary* in the code snippet with .alert-fixed.

Hope this helps.

```css
.card{
    width: 14rem; 
    height: 8rem; 
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    transition: 0.3s;
    color: #333333;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
   
}
.card:hover{ 
    background-color: rgba(71, 172, 255,1);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.card-body{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.alert-fixed
{
position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 50px;
    
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card-group">

               <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5>.....Some Text.....</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

             
                 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5>.....Some Text.....</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
      </div>
        </div>
 
            
        <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
  This is a primary alert—check it out!
</div>
            
     
            </div>
```

Comment: I use information first time and it doesn't help on first time. So, I changed position: absolute; to position: fixed; and it works. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Adding this might help

```
.alert-box{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 80vw;
}
```

`position: fixed;` fixes the position, `bottom: 10px` will offset the alertbox 10px from bottom and `width: 80vw;` will keep it's width according to the viewport size.

Comment: I try this but it dosn't help. However, I use information from your comment and Stamina's comment and it works! Thanks very much!

.alert-fixed
{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 50px;   
}